# Can I search if an interval is between another interval?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, intervals

I need to search if a date, or any day 30 days from that date is between an interval. Is that achievable somehow using postgresql?

Comment: You can simply compare dates or timestamps as in `my_date between date '2022-01-01' and date '2022-01-30'`. Or... you can use a `daterange` (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check for interval overlaps:

```
SELECT daterange(current_date, current_date + 31) && '[2022-01-01,2022-01-31]';
```

There is also `tsrange` for ranges of `timestamp` and `tstzrange` for ranges of `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: I got to the same information yesterday night. If it is of anyone's use, note that, depending on postgresql version, you might have to use a different syntax for dateranges and 'overlaps' instead of '&&'